# Getting a file from API ( Guzzle, Laravel, PHP )

Tags: php, api, laravel-5.3, fwrite, guzzle

I will love to get a file from an API using Laravel / Guzzle.

```
$API_Conn = $factory->create(new Client(), MemoQWSAPI::FileManager());

$chunkSize = 500000;

$file_start = $API_Conn->call('BeginChunkedFileDownload', [[
    'fileGuid' => $file_Guid,
    'zip' => false,
]]);

$fileStream = fopen(storage_path('/app/MemoQWSAPI/test.xliff'), 'w');

$fileBytesLeft = $file_start->fileSize;

while($fileBytesLeft > 0){
    $chunkBytes = $API_Conn->call('GetNextFileChunk', [[ 
        'sessionId' => $file_start->BeginChunkedFileDownloadResult,
        'chunkSize' => $chunkSize,
    ]]);

    $write = fwrite($fileStream, $chunkBytes, $chunkSize);

    $fileBytesLeft -= $chunkSize;
}

$res = $API_Conn->call('EndChunkedFileDownload', [[ 
    'sessionId' => $file_start->BeginChunkedFileDownloadResult,
]]);

fclose($fileStream);

$API_Conn->call('DeleteFile', [[ // Export the file in to a Xliff File
    'fileGuid' => $file_Guid,
]]);
```

I get the file from API with this call:

```
$chunkBytes = $API_Conn->call('GetNextFileChunk', [[ 
    'sessionId' => $file_start->BeginChunkedFileDownloadResult,
    'chunkSize' => $chunkSize,
]]);
```

I use this to save the file:

```
$fileStream = fopen(storage_path('/app/MemoQWSAPI/test.xliff'), 'w');

fwrite($fileStream, $chunkBytes, $chunkSize);

fclose($fileStream);
```

The problem is I'm not getting any data from the API.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question if the API is unknown to us. Does the API return any error? Your code doesn't even seem to check for error messages from API.

Comment: There's 3 calls:
1. 'BeginChunkedFileDownload` -> I got a SessionId and fileSize.
2.'GetNextFileChunk' -> To iterate
3. 'EndChunkedFileDownload' ->To Close.

On API Specs are programmed on C# and I reproduced this code on PHP, but the way to get the data from 2.Step with fwrite, does't get any data.

If I execute this code like that fwrite give me an error: 

fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given.

Comment: If you have an error from `fwrite`, you should investigate what type `$chunkBytes` is. It should be mentioned in the API specification or in the documentation of the PHP class (`$API_Conn`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, but finally I found the error.

That was because the API server automatically creates a file with the name Test.xliff, but how is saved on server is, Test.xliff.dff89302a093s8402934a23948, filename + token.

Anyway thank you to all of you.